# How to use a variable with class name inside a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a variable x which counts the number of fields added to a form dynamically. I want to remove a field for which I tried to use the following code. But I can't.

```js
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $( "div" ).remove( ".org-details\'+(x-1)+\'" );x--;
    })
});
```

I want the output be something like this on runtime.

```js
$( "div" ).remove( ".org-details1" );
```

Please help.

Comment: `$("div").remove(\`.org-details${--x}\`)`

Comment: Thank you too. This too works.

Comment: FYI. if you use this you don't need to use `x--;` after `remove` as `--x` decrements and returns the value after decrementing.

Comment: Thanks again. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (note the backticks):

```
$("div").remove(`.org-details${x-1}`)
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.